# Вивчення української для польськомовної людини

Tags: вивчення-мови

Які можете порекомендувати ресурси/сайти/підручники для вивчення української? Основна моя проблема у тому що більшість авторів пропонують вивчення української через англійську, що практично не має сенсу у випадку поляка. Тож шукаю підручників чи інших ресурсів що пропонують або вивчення української як іноземної не спираючись на конкретну іноземну мову.

Answer (score 2):

Начебто існує [такий підручник](https://www.nas.gov.ua/publications/books/SiteBook/Pages/default.aspx?ffn1=ISBN&fft1=Eq&ffv1=978-83-7720-145-9):
[image: Bożena Zinkiewicz-Tomanek, Oksana Baraniwska «Język ukraiński dla początkujących», «Petrus»]
(Bożena Zinkiewicz-Tomanek, Oksana Baraniwska «Język ukraiński dla początkujących»; 2012, Kraków, «Petrus»; ISBN 978-83-7720-145-9).

Також натрапляв на лекції на YouTube:

- [Nauka języka ukraińskiego](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLvbG4CGGTyRIiEeVWoXE1tvzRUMkDgoBE).
- [500 Zwroty Ukraińskie dla Początkujących](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7pG_pZbj5lQ).
- [[Nauka Jezyka] Ukraiński od podstaw](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qk5UTuaOenk).

Але наскільки те все підходить, сказати важко (бо я навіть не володію польською).

Comment: Дякую за відповідь. Досить цікаво, особливо що всюди є аудіоматеріали. Проте мені більш цікаво було знайти саме українського авторства ресурси. Але з Твоїх посилань теж знайшла для себе кілька речей, тож подяка :)

Comment: До речі, у підручника є продовження — «Język ukraiński dla średniozaawansowanych».